# What is the optimal way to align buttons and text? Basic, but necessary due to misinformation online

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, layout

I've seen a lot of different topics and suggestions on aligning and inputting buttons/text, but the ways I've seen seem kind of risky.

What is the optimal way, for example, to add two buttons, stack them together, and have them be 10% from the bottom of the screen, and centered horizontally on all devices?

Comment: Can you give one or two examples of what you have seen, why you think that it is "kind of risky" or "misinformation online"? That would be more constructive instead of only asking for another  solution.

Comment: Auto-layout, Auto-layout..learning it is bit tricky, but you should use it. Some can provide you answer with full diagrammatical explanation. But it will be of no use if you don't have basic info about Auto-layout. Check internet for tutorials. If there's is some issues during implementing that by yourself , feel  free to ask here with specific problem.

Comment: I added the `layout` tag, and removed `swift` (question applies equally to both Swift and Objective-C).

Comment: thank you everyone for the quick responses, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your Storyboard and add [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html) to your elements. Here is an example:
[image]

I have added auto layout

- Left
- Right
- Top
- Bottom

If I want to change the distance between the buttons, I just choose the auto layout constraint that I have created between the buttons and changes the constant value to it.

If I say that "Button 4" constant to the top shall be 40, then it´s always 40 no matter what size the phone has. If I change the constant between the buttons to 10 then it´s the same for all sizes.

Answer (score 2):

The optimal way would be using storyboard for implementation and use of constraints in a proper way.
For example, as you suggested you want bottom space to be 10% of device height so it can be done with the multiplier in constraints also the horizontal center can be easily done with the same, so you could look for a good tutorial of Auto Layout and constraints for better understanding.

Comment: Where exactly is this multiplayer, and same for horizontal center? Whenever I do it, I get warnings, and always have to fix it using "update constraints" which is very annoying.

Comment: whenever you add a spacing Constraint it gets added in the constraints stack of that particular view. so by selecting that view you can edit that particular constraint so into that you will find that multiplier thing below the priority option. you may go through some tutorials if you want

Answer (score 2):

Learn Auto Layout if you haven't yet. Use constraints for achieving the following:

> 1. For centrally Horizontal on all devices: Use Center X with SuperView.
> 2. For having them 10% from bottom, use multiplier value say **0.10** .

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html). It takes a bit of learning but once you get used to it you can add constraints pretty quickly and easily in Interface Builder. I can't recommend any particular guide but there are a lot of good ones to be found with a quick Internet search.

Here is an example of constraints that seem to be what you are looking for:

[image: Auto Layout Constraints]
[image: iPhone 4-inch Portrait]
[image: iPhone 4-inch Landscape]

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 9, an even simpler Auto Layout approach would be to use [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/).

As you can see, no constraints are needed for the buttons embedded in the stack view, as the stack view lays out the buttons for you.  All you have to constrain is the location of the stack view itself.

Here's an example of two vertically stacked buttons, 10% from the bottom of the screen, and centered horizontally for all devices.

[image]